# Android recyclerview newly added item was blocked by appbarlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I was doing this app on android and noticed that when I add a new item to recyclerview at the top, the item will be blocked by appbarlayout.[app screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InfMj.png)

For example if I add a new item, it will show as the first item on on top of "444", but after adding I have to scroll down to see it, otherwise it is blocked by the appbarlayout.

Is there a solution to this? Thanks.

layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/crime_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_fragment"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the new item on top, call `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

Comment: This is not exactly a work around. Recycler view doesn't automatically scrolls when data is changed.

Comment: Thank you! So every time something changed, I have to scroll manually?

Comment: If you want to show those rows. For example if you are building a chat view, you need to scroll to the bottom after update. However, if you are building a infinite scrollable list you dont want list to scroll when new data is updated.

Comment: I called onRestoreInstanceState() to resume last time's position, and I added a if statement to see if it is a update or a insert, to determine whether to scroll to first or to last  time's position

Comment: Thank you for your solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Call  `notifyItemChanged(position);` after adding an item in your adapter

Comment: I called it, and the item is added, just blocked by the appbar

Comment: Don't give match_parent height to your recyclerView. Make it fill_parent

Comment: Please rate my answer.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that it works with fill_parent and doesn't work with match_parent?

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake, this is actually not working

Comment: what was the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/collapse_toolbar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/expand_title_btm_margin"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/expand_title_end_margin"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expand_title_start_margin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/no_poster"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I had a similar problem but this one solved it for me... plz try and let me know... I have checked it in only one device in portrait mode.

place your recycler view below the appbarlayout and then close the coordinate layout tag

Please remove the imageview if it is unnecessary to you..

Comment: the item is still blocked

Comment: can you post the complete code here so that I'll be able to see if the problem exists else where? please...

Answer (score 0):

When you add items , RecyclerView does not scroll to new items position automatically. You need to scroll it pragmatically when you add new item. AppbarLayout does not a culprit here. Just scroll your RView to new item's position by following line of code.

```
  this.notifyItemRangeInserted(startingPosition, noOfItemsInserted);//or this.notifyItemInserted(newItemPosition);
  ((LinearLayoutManager) mListRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(newItemPosition, 0);
```

In your case just scroll to position zero.

Comment: I called onRestoreInstanceState in the fragment code, kinda wish to remember the position of scroll of last time